# How to HIDE text with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Have this code:

```
<h4 class="ihf-price" style="margin-right:10px;">
   <span class="ihf-for-sale-price"> $16,750,000 </span> (Fee Simple)
</h4> </div> </div>
```

How do I hide the text "(Fee Simple)" from displaying?

Want the Price to show but not the "Fee Simple" text

Comment: wrap it on a span and use display:none.

Comment: @FacundoCorradini if he can wrap it on span so he can simply remove it then, no ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif probably. Can't guess with such an incomplete and poor question as it was when  we commented (no code provided at all), can we?

Comment: @FacundoCorradini i agree with this but my reflexion beyond the question was : why not simply recommend to remove the element instead of recommend to update the html and then add CSS to remove it :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif indeed. But at the moment, I thought there must have some reason he couldn't remove it, but don't want to show it. Probably  wanted to keep it there for alternative styles, e.g. hiding it only when on mobile, keeping it there for print and not screen, etc.  So spanning the part that would be hidden would have made some sense.... but anyway, it was just a really, really poor question.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a font-size trick like this:

```css
h4.ihf-price {
  font-size: 0;
}

h4.ihf-price span {
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="ihf-price" style="margin-right:10px;">
  <span class="ihf-for-sale-price"> $16,750,000 </span> (Fee Simple)
</h4>
```

Or use color trick if you want to maintain the same content width of `h4`:

```css
h4.ihf-price {
  color: #fff; /* Should be the same as background */
}

h4.ihf-price span {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="ihf-price" style="margin-right:10px;">
  <span class="ihf-for-sale-price"> $16,750,000 </span> (Fee Simple)
</h4>
```

Comment: Font-size approach makes more sense than color or visibility ones for 99% of use cases, as the "hidden" part will not take space on the flow, and therefore allow borders, backgrounds etc to work correctly and don't interfere with other elements positioning :)

Comment: @FacundoCorradini yes sure, i don't advise the color one too much but in some cases (that i faced before) we need to keep the width of content because of some alignment or other stuffs. So changing color won't change any position or alignment but of course this remain relative as we don't know the real context of this, maybe it's useless and the font-size trick will do it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Hide text in the entire element. Show text only in the nested element.

```css
.ihf-price {
  font-size: 0;
}

.ihf-for-sale-price {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="ihf-price" style="margin-right:10px;">
  <span class="ihf-for-sale-price"> $16,750,000 </span> (Fee Simple)
</h4>
```

OR

```css
.ihf-price {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ihf-for-sale-price {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="ihf-price" style="margin-right:10px;">
  <span class="ihf-for-sale-price"> $16,750,000 </span> (Fee Simple)
</h4>
```

Comment: intresting the visibility trick ... i always thought it works like opacity and display : if applied to parent you cannot override it in child element

Comment: the only issue is that you cannot apply styling to h4 like border, background,etc

Comment: Yeah, `visibility` is different in that way too. `display: none` and `opacity` wouldn't work here. And right about the border, background, etc. on the parent. But that was beyond the scope of this question. @TemaniAfif

Comment: yes sure, it's out of the scope but it was a bit strange for me as i just discover it now, i didn't knew it before ;)